# Как не создавать файл db.sq-journal используя sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, aiogram, sqlalchemy

Я новичок, и хотел бы узнать, как сделать так, чтобы не создавался журнал. На своём пк, когда я открываю свой проект и запускаю его, все сразу пишется напрямую в файл `db`. Никаких журналов не создаётся. Я сразу вижу все данные в записанные в файл `db`.

У меня простой проект на `python` с ботом в телеге. Использовал `aiogram` и `sqlalchemy`.

Когда проект закидываю на сервер, запускаю его там, то все работает, но данные пишутся не в `db` , а в файл `db.sq-journal`, при этом он не удаляется, он постоянно торчит в папке!

Я читал, что он как резерв должен быть, но и должен закрываться и после закрытия все данные помещаются уже в сам файл `db`. Но у меня этот журнал не закрывается никогда. Все данные хранятся в этом журнале а в сам файл базы данных ничего не записывается. И если я бота перезапускаю, то все данные теряются....

Помогите новичку пожалуйста, слишком сложный вопрос для меня.

Читал что можно через `pragma` как то влиять, но я не понимаю как это осуществить в `sqlalchemy`.

Comment: Это вопрос конкретного проекта. Мы не решим эту проблему по описанию. Вникай в код или найди человека, кто поможет тебе с проектом лично.

Comment: Но ведь у меня этот же проект на компе моем запускается и склалчеми работает без журнала. Почему может не работать на удаленном серваке, все остальные проекты работают норм там, правда именно склалчеми впервый раз решил попробовать.